# Run time error #13 - type mismatch (if range ... then ...)

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I need to scan certain cells in a range. If some cells are empty, then the message "cell is empty" will be written in that particular empty cell. I have been trying the following:

```
    Sub Empty()

       Sheets("My sheet").Select
       If Range("C5:C12,C15:C22,C25:C32,C36:C43,C46:C53,C56:C63,C66:C73,C76:C83,D4,D14,D24,D35,D45,D55,D65,D75").Value = "" Then
          Range("C5:C12,C15:C22,C25:C32,C36:C43,C46:C53,C56:C63,C66:C73,C76:C83,D4,D14,D24,D35,D45,D55,D65,D75").Value = "cell is empty"
       End If
    End sub

I am getting the error: run time error #13 - type mismatch.
```

---

> So as to help any other folks that may have had the same problem as me, **I am going to complement the working solutions presented below.** Note that I added an error handling that prevents the message "run time error '1004': No Cells were found" and also an Array to scan specific worksheets that match your needs:

```
    Sub myEmpty()
        Dim rng As Range
        On Error GoTo NoBlanks   
        Dim MyArray As Worksheet

        For Each MyArray In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
          Select Case MyArray.Name
            Case Is = "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3", "Sheet n-1", "Sheet n"

            With MyArray
            Set rng = .Range("C5:C12,C15:C22,C25:C32,C36:C43,C46:C53,C56:C63,C66:C73,C76:C83,D4,D14,D24,D35,D45,D55,D65,D75")
              If CBool(Application.CountBlank(rng)) Then
                rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "cell is empty"
              End If
            End With

          Case Else
          End Select
          Next MyArray

NoBlanks:

 CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "   There are no empty cells", 0.7, "INfo:"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) property after determining that there is one or more blank cells.

```
Sub myEmpty()
    dim rng as range
    with Sheets("My sheet")
        set rng = .Range("C5:C12,C15:C22,C25:C32,C36:C43,C46:C53,C56:C63,C66:C73,C76:C83,D4,D14,D24,D35,D45,D55,D65,D75")
        If cbool(application.countblank(rng)) then
            rng.specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "cell is empty"
        End If
    end with
End sub
```

Empty and IsEmpty are reserved words in VBA. It is usually best best avoiding their repurpose.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error 13 because calling `.Value` on a Range that includes multiple cells returns an array of Variant. You can't apply one condition to multiple cells in a Range with an If statement like that either - you need to use a loop and test individual cells:

```
Public Sub FlagEmptyCells()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("C5:C12,C15:C22,C25:C32,C36:C43,C46:C53,C56:C63,C66:C73,C76:C83,D4,D14,D24,D35,D45,D55,D65,D75")

    Dim current As Range
    For Each current In target
        If current.Value = vbNullString Then current.Value = "cell is empty"
    Next
End Sub
```

Note also that you can't have a Sub named `Empty` - it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: Comintern, your solution  is also a good option. Thank you for your time!